# How to hide controllers/buttons in Pictometry IPA javascript?

Tags: javascript, hide, gis, controllers

I want to hide the buttons/controllers from the Pictometry IPA javascript. The buttons like Export/Import as PDF, dual panes etc. I've researched a lot regarding this but couldn't find anything satisfactory. Can you please help me out?